# I try to add a list at a specific key but list empty in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
for student_id in range(1,len(student)+1):
    for test_id in range(len(marks)):
        if marks["student_id"][test_id] == student_id:
            test_list.append(marks["test_id"][test_id])
    
    test_dict[student_id] = [test_list]
    test_list.clear()

print(test_dict)
```

I made some test and the list contents some result before adding the list to the dictionary but in the dictionary it is empty. When I searched on the internet, everything looks normal.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] and include some test data.

Comment: Ok I will pay attention to that in the future. Thank you for mentioning that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more pythonic way would be something like this:

```py
for student_id in range(1,len(student)+1):
    
    # make a new list for every iteration
    test_list = []
    
    for test_id in range(len(marks)):
        if marks["student_id"][test_id] == student_id:
            test_list.append(marks["test_id"][test_id])
    
    test_dict[student_id] = test_list # no additional []
    # no .clear()

print(test_dict)
```